# Spring Data JPA Naming Strategy - Using Camel Case

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I know there are a lot of questions/answers available on this topic. Unfortunately, none of them has helped me.

I have defined an `Entity`.

```
@Entity
public class SimpleEntity ...
```

Now I want that the mapping to the relational database should work with same name as the one of the entity. Just plain camel case `SimpleEntity`. To my surprise it doesn't work. As default `Spring Data JPA` maps it to snake case.

I have read a lot of answers. A solution which was multiple times propagated was to set the physical naming strategy.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Setting this option changes the mapping naming to the lower case variant `simpleentity`. This might be fine when a database is used which is case insensitive but `PostgreSQL` isn't.

<strike>I also read in the hibernate docs that setting the implicit naming strategy should be used to define the implicit mapping (since I haven't defined any table name). But regardless which setting I'm using as implicit naming strategy the mapping remains the same.</strike> Got it, implicit naming strategy is just the logical name mapping.

I am using

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.8.RELEASE
PostgreSQL Version 10.0
```

I have defined the hibernate dialect with the proper value for my database `PostgreSQLDialect` respective `PostgreSQL95Dialect`.

I know I can implement a custom `PhysicalNamingStrategy`. But I just want to have the same table names like my entity names. This should be the standard case, easy as pie, using plain `JPA` + `Hibernate` works fine out of the box without any configuration. So why is making Spring such a big deal?

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me after struggling for a while.

1. In your application.properties add:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

2. Annotate SimpleEntity with the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"tblEmployees\"")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "\"empID\"")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
```

Later your insert at the console will look like this:

> INSERT INTO tblEmployees (empID, ...) VALUES (22, ...)

Comment: This solution works. Tried it with Spring Boot `2.2.6.RELEASE` and `PostgreSQL 14.8`